# How can I call username from sql with ajax in flask?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I've tried to call username column information from SQL with ajax but comes only 1st id's username, but I want all of them

this is the model

```
class users(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True)
    email=db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True)
    password=db.Column(db.String(100))
    posts=db.relationship('posts',backref='user')
    picture=db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

this is the route

```
@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    user=None
    if request.method == "POST":
    user=users.query.all()
    for i in user:
        return (i.username)

return render_template('test.html',user=user)
```

this is html code

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block title %}
    Test Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content_title %}
   <h1 class="text-center"> Please Tests</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <button class="usersList btn btn-info">Users List</button>
{% endblock %}
```

and this is my js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $(".usersList").click(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "/test/",
            dataType:'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success:function(response){

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you have return statement in your loop

Comment: but when I want to append into the array ,it appends only 1st username

Comment: `return jsonify([u.username for u in users])   # rename user to users in your code`

Comment: user_n=None
    new=[]
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_n=users.query.all()
        for i in user_n:
            new.append(i.username)
        new=str(new)
        return new

I change my loop and now it prints my username,but if Iwant to see all table information I must append every column,but if I have 30columns it not good idea
Do You have an idea what to do,without appending every column?

Comment: @GevorgManukyan That's a new question entirely. Please create a new post for this. However, it's not clear to me why you want your user instances in JSON format when you have a template that allows you to use them directly.

Comment: @shmee I do it ,for api,with ajax

Comment: you should use any marshaling/unmarshaling tool for serializing your models to json. marshmallow for example

Answer (score 1):

Something to remember is that the function

```py
    @app.route('/test/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def test():
```

will only get called ONCE for each time you do that ajax request. The way we are trying to implement the functionality here, our flask application needs to build the WHOLE list of users and then return the WHOLE list of users.

The function should only be returning the result of the render_template call, which should include all the users. What's happening here is that our "return(i) username" is being hit and returning the first user, before our render_template is even called.

In other words, when the "return" statement gets hit, the function returns whatever we have told it to immediately and the rest of the function never gets executed.

I've modified the code slightly

```py
    @app.route('/test/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def test():
        #you're only returning one value like this
        #user=None

        #use a list to hold all the users returned from the query instead
        users=[]

        if request.method == "POST":
        user=users.query.all()
        for i in user:
            #don't do this
            #return (i.username)

            #do this instead
            username = i.username
            users.append(username)    
    return render_template('test.html',users=users)
```

then, in our html template, we want to iterate over the returned list and render an element for each of the username items. Something like the following might get you started:

```html
    <h2>Usernames</h2>
    {% for username in usernames %}
      <span>{{username}}</span>
    {% endfor %}
```

I hope this helps you